# Gcc: Memory region for anonymous string

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, compilation

I used GCC and need to define big array of text, like

```
const char* myArray[1000] = {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow", ...};
```

I have a array of pointers and big heap of text like `"red\0blue\0green\0..."` somewere in memory. I want to change memory region for that text. I used `__attribute__((section(...)))` GCC directive, but they change only allocation of pointers. How can i change allocation of big text chunk? Thanks for answers.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Could you provide some idea of **why** you want to do this? That might help figure out how to accomplish what you need, but I suspect this isn't a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use -fdata-sections with gcc. That will create a unique section for each global variable in the object-file.

Then you can create a LdScript-file which will tell the linker (ld) to put the sections into the desired memory region.

Anonymous strings are in the .rodata-section of the object-file. An LdScript-example snippet:

```
.memregion1.rodata :
{ 
    Startup.c.obj(.rodata.str1.8)
}
```

will put the str1.8 from Startup.c into the memregion1.

Comment: This or (the rather ugly) solution of doing something like: `const char red[] __attribute__((section("mytext"))) = "red"; const char blue[] __attribute__((section("mytext"))) = "blue"; const char* myArray[] = { red, blue, ... };`